# problem computing/parsing oggs/opus audio files header

Tags: parsing, audio, ogg, opus

I am reading an ogg audio file header and am having some difficulty understanding how to compute the location of the next ogg file segment. i was able to use this webpage as an example: [https://www.file-recovery.com/ogg-signature-format.htm](https://www.file-recovery.com/ogg-signature-format.htm#:%7E:text=OGG%20files%20are%20organized%20into,end%20of%20the%20audio%20file.) using this example.ogg file i was able to compute the right locations of the oggs headers.

BUT... in the example link, at offset (dec) 128 + 1 there is  `FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF B6` and calculating this is simple, 12*255 = 3060, 3060 + 182 (hex B6) = 3242, 3242 + 1 + 13 + 128 = 3384. so from the start of the last read header 0x3A (dec 58), if i seek a total of 3384 bytes, i am exactly at the spot of the next ogg file header.

now, where my problem comes in is this. in a real ogg/opus file, the values to calculate where the next ogg header are slightly confusing me. here is an image hopefully it will make it a little easier to get my problem across.

[image]

i am not sure how to proceed here. 0x48 = dec 72. so i would assume that there are 72 records here that are 3 bytes long each? that doesnt make sense. Or would it be 72 records, and the 0x03 at offset 0xAC is just part of the calculation? this is confusing to me, and i am not sure if i am asking the question right. but what i am trying to do is just parse the whole ogg file from top to bottom. im not looking to do any sort of processing at each header (yet) and i just need to fogire out the correct way to calculate these ogg header/segment location. if i need to elaborate on anything please ask and i will do my best. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to figure this out. was just a simple misunderstanding on my part. when you read (as in the example above) 0x48 = dec 72. next add current position in file, then add 72 to that, then add/sum the next 72 characters, whatever they may be. this will give you the offset ((from the beginning of the file) of the next ogg entry